Relation between regularity and uniformity of certain hypergraphs.
I am not expecting a complete solution to the problem but more like relevant theorems and literature that might be useful in solving the problem or part of it.
Say we have k-regular hypergraph that admits a unique probability model over its vertices. By probability model I mean that each vertex is assigned a probability value such that sum of those values along any hyperedge is one.
Do these constraints imply that the hypergraph must also be uniform?
I have tried to tackle this problem by using the incidence matrix of the hypergraph. The rows of the incidence matrix owing to above constraints on the hypergraph must then have same number of ones (regularity), the matrix has unique solutions to the matrix equation $x^TA=1$ (unique probability model) and tried to see whether this forces each column to have the same number of ones (uniformity).
I have tried generating counter examples where the hypergraph under such constraints is not uniform but haven't been able to find any, so a counterexample or a proof of the theorem is required. I would like to know about any theorems graph theoretic or linear algebraic that might answer the question.

No. Consider the hypergraph $H$ with vertices $V(H) = \{a, b, c\}$ with edges $$E(H) = \left\{\{a\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\},\{b,c\}\right\}.$$ The only probability model on $H$ assigns $a$ and $c$ a value of one, and $b$ a value of zero.
We can also come up with an example without using edges of size one. Observe that odd cycles force all their vertices have value $1/2$. This implies that any hyperedge containing two vertices of an odd cycle assigns $0$ value to its other vertices. Let $G$ be the hypergraph below. $G$ has a unique probability model, but is not regular because it has some vertices of degree three and three vertices, say $u, v,$ and $w$, of degree $2$.
$\hspace{9.5em}$ 
Let $G'$ be a copy of $G$ with vertices $u', v', w'$ being the copies of $u, v, w$. Add a new vertex $x$ and hyperedges $\{u,u',x\}, \{v,v',x\}, \{w,w',x\}$, and call the resulting hypergraph $G''$. Then $G''$ is $3$-regular, has a unique probability model, but is not uniform.
I cannot immediately think of a counterexample where the all edges have size more than two.
